# cognos greenplum pg_catalog

Tags: cognos, greenplum

I am using Cognos report and Greenplum database.

My report is taking too much time too run. So I looked at the green plum log, and discover that half of the time where spent querying the pg_catalog. In the catalog i am not looking at the pg_catalog but on other tables, so i don't understand why the cognos decide to look at the pg_catalog table.

When i run cognos report i can see from the greenplum log, that a for some of the query, cognos run select on pg_catalog before running the query.

Why is this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Greenplum but the pg_catalog table sounds like a system catalog containing metadata.  Depending on the type of query being issued, Cognos will sometimes make metadata requests to the database to help make decisions about how to handle a query.  When you made the report, is it based off of a Framework Manager model/package, or are you using custom SQL in the report?

Answer (score 0):

pg_catalog contains metadata about tables, columns and other database objects.
I think your problem is catalog bloat. Basically, if you need to wait few seconds to list tables (using \d in psql) then you should vacuum your catalog.

Check "Chapter 19: Routine System Maintenance Tasks" - "Regular System Catalog Maintenance" in GP admin guide.

> Greenplum recommends that you periodically run VACUUM on the system
>   catalog to clear the space occupied by deleted objects. If numerous
>   DROP statements are a part of regular database operations, it is safe
>   and appropriate to run a system catalog maintenance procedure with
>   VACUUM daily at off-peak hours. This can be done while the system is
>   running and available. The following example script performs a VACUUM
>   of the Greenplum Database system catalog:

```
#!/bin/bash
DBNAME="<database_name>"
VCOMMAND="VACUUM ANALYZE"
psql -tc "select '$VCOMMAND' || ' pg_catalog.' || relname || ';' from pg_class a,pg_namespace b where a.relnamespace=b.oid and b.nspname= 'pg_catalog' and a.relkind='r'" $DBNAME | psql -a $DBNAME
```